# Azure Resource Graph Explorer result is cached?

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-resource-graph

When I use the "New Query" option on Azure Resource Graph Explorer page, the "Run Query" button is disabled.
When I use a sample query it is enabled and works, but when I update the query with any changes, I can run it but it keeps showing the result from the original query that I had opened. Seems like the result is caches or something.

Any ideas if this is a bug on the Azure portal or what?

Comment: I think the portal was broken temporarily yesterday. it works as expected today.

Answer (score 0):

> When I use the "New Query" option on Azure Resource Graph Explorer page, the "Run Query" button is disabled.

Yes, It is disabled at first as there is nothing to run or execute like below:

[image]

Then when I enter a character like below and `run query` is enabled as below:

[image]

Ran sample query as below:

[image]

then my query:

[image]

You can see it has changed, If you are seeing same results then I guess then the results of both queries are same even after filtering or producing same outputs.

Now trying with saving a query:

[image]

Sometimes, when you are saving it, it does not save immediately:

[image]

Its still showing previous saved results(as the results are not saved even after saving):

[image]

You need to click on `Save` or `Ctrl S` for 2 or 3 times then it will be saved:

[image]

This is a expected behavior in Azure Resource Graph Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share with you the latest status of the issue and it's not very glorious :)

The issue ix fixed just by empying the web browser cache or by using an Incognito session of the brower.

Hope it can help if you are experiencing the same issue.